# Constructing a line perpendicular to one of two given intersecting lines by first drawing a circle

Tags: geometry

> Suppose there are two intersecting lines $\ell$ and $m$ in the plane. Using only a compass and straightedge, first draw a circle $c$ and then a line $p$ so that the line $p$ is perpendicular to the line $\ell$. Justify your answer.

It seems you draw lines from center to the intersection points of the line with circle then this is isosceles triangle what will be an angle bisector to the line from center.

Am I right?

Comment: How can I edit it to say two lines  , l and m

Comment: See if the edits make sense

Comment: Is that really all they have to say about line $m$? Just that it intersects line $l$, nothing else to do with anything? And the circle $c$ -- why can't we just draw it anywhere, then ignore it and proceed to construct the line $p$?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property of the circumscribed right angled triangles:

Let $l\cap m=A$.

Choose any point $O\in m$.

Draw a circle $c$ centered at $O$ through the point $A$.

Let $l \cap c =C$, $m \cap c =B$, $AB$ is the diameter of $c$.

Then $\triangle ABC$ is right angled, and $p=BC \perp l$.

[image]